# CUDA 7.0 installation not detecting Visual Studio 2013 Express

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, cuda

I am trying to install CUDA 7.0 on my laptop.  It's Windows 7 64-bit with Visual Studio for Desktop 2013 Express.  I get the error message "No supported version of Visual Studio was found."  In the [CUDA documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html#axzz3Y00NGpyZ) it specifies that VS 2013 is supported (however it doesn't mention the Express version). Any advice please?

Comment: VS Express does not support plugin, so the error you're getting is probably from the CUDA integration with VS (Nsight plugin IIRC). However the driver, compiler and libraries should install just fine.

Comment: Ok but how do i fix that?

Comment: Should I just go ahead and install regardless?

Answer (score 9):

Visual Studio 2013 Express is not a supported version for CUDA 7.0.

The supported versions are listed in [the windows getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements).

Switch to a supported version.

If you are looking for a "free" Visual Studio version, use Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.  This has some advantages anyway, over the express versions:

1. 64-bit compiler support
2. VS Plugin support (so you can use nsight VSE, although the warning message you received is not unique to nsight VSE.  The CUDA 7 installer will report that.)